# How to display last 10 logins into the system?

Tags: command-line

I used

```
last
```

to display last 10 logins, but it displays me all of them.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but are you the only one that uses the machine? Mine lists myself and the various reboots that occurred...

Comment: It is a remote server (mine of course), but I want just last 10 logins to be displayed and I don't know exactly how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `last -n 10` or `last -num 10`.

Comment: "last -n 10" seems to work. I tried "last -num 10" before and it didn't

Comment: Glad to be of service. Have a look here for more info on last http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_last.htm